# How to get a image source from a webpage's source in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, html

I am trying to make a program easy enough my co-workers can use it. The program takes the inputted image ID number, adds it to the static link, and downloads the image. The problem is to get the image ID you have to view the pages source code. Is there a way I can have it so I input the document number / link and it automatically gets the image source from the webpage's source?

If you need to look at an example, here is a random example document: http://ori2.polk-county.net/wb_or1/details.asp?doc_id=7029941&file_num=2008093164

Also, I am using C#

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your documents are all accessed through the same URL .http://ori2.polk-county.net/wb_or1/details.asp

You can use the WebRequest class to POST your doc_id and file_num. You should then receive the image in the response.

[This is a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

Comment: No, the image is located in: http://http://ori2.polk-county.net/wb_or1/image.asp (E.G http://ori2.polk-county.net/wb_or1/image.asp?table=img_web&image_id=16178790)

This link is located in the page source, so I was wondering if I could input the original link (http://ori2.polk-county.net/wb_or1/details.asp?doc_id=7029941&file_num=2008093164) and have my code get the link in the source (image.asp?table=img_web&image_id=16178790). 

Sorry if it is hard to understand, I'm not really sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Then you should be able to fetch the page using HTTP GET (still using the WebRequest class), parse the XML that is returned (aka HTML) and extract the link. Once you have that my answer fills in the rest